# What is the mount point for reserve space

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lvm, ext4, system-reserved-partition

While reinstalling Ubuntu 17.10, found a 767MB of ext4 partition along side 536MB EFI and 248GB Encrypted LVM partition.

After reading few articles I figure that the 767MB space is reserved space for root. But I have no idea where to mount this partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount it wherever you want. 
Common choices are `/mnt` and `/mnt/something`,
but you can mount it under your home directory if you want.

You realize that it needs to have a filesystem on it before you can mount it,
right?

Comment: Thanks G-Man, I kind of found the reason for 767mb of ext4 space. Since the 248gb was Encrypted, including the root partition. Kernel and boot files had to be separated. The 767mb is mounted as boot.